# The sequence $(x_n)$ diverges, then $(\sqrt[3]{x_n})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove if it is true or not. I really tried with some definitions and propositions and I could not reach the answer.

Comment: Instead of : If P then Q, try to prove the contrapositive. If not Q then not P

Comment: @Spvf Since $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ is a continuous function, you have that
$$ \lim \sqrt[3]{x_n} = \sqrt[3]{\lim x_n}$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: @PierreCarre ... For the "diverge" version of the question, you need the opposite direction is continuous: $x \mapsto x^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\sqrt[3]{x_n}$ converges. Then we know, that we can multiply two converge sequence and obtain $\sqrt[3]{x_{n}^2}$ converges. Multiplying once more gives, that $x_n$ converges. Now you can use this implication to obtain your sentence.

Comment: Pretty usefull thanks